# Auto Scroll to Bottom DIV

Tags: jquery, css

I have made chat system, but I had a problem with scrolling div for the messages that the scroll bar must be at the bottom as default.

**DIV**

```
<div class="chat-body chat-scroll" id="chat-scroll"></div>
```

**STYLE**

```
.chat-scroll{position: absolute; top:0px; bottom: 0px; overflow-y: auto;}
```

I use JQuery for submit message from the input form to reload the content of the #chat-scroll
and the auto scrolling is okay for submit, but when at first load of the page, the scroll only stays at the middle of the div #chat-scroll. Unlike if I submit a message it will go to the bottom when I send message.

**JQuery For Scrolling**

```
$('#chat-scroll').animate({
scrollTop: $('#chat-scroll').get(0).scrollHeight}, 2000);
```

Comment: can you share the demo using fiddle or codepen.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

When window load scroll your chat div at bottom using `document.ready`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/5RY2v/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#chat-scroll').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#chat-scroll').get(0).scrollHeight
    }, 2000);
});
```